# Onclick button not responding to multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, node.js, onclick

I am fetching a video from `aws S3` on `onclick event`.

Problem 1:  Every time I upload a new video, I have to reload to use the button again.The button is not responding to multiple clicks

Problem 2: The older video is playing even though am fetching a new video. I have tried clearing the cookies. Nothing works.

```
<body>
<button  id="getvideo">get video</button>
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls><source type="video/mp4"></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
const button = document.getElementById("getvideo");
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     console.log('button was clicked');
     fetch('/clicked', {method: 'GET'})
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.ok) {
            var url = response.url;
            var data = url.substring(28)
            var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
            document.querySelector("#myVideo > source").src = data;
            document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
            return;
        }
        throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
 });
</script>
</body>
```

Here is my route:

```
    import express from 'express';
    import get_video from '../controllers/getVideo.controller';

    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('', (req, res) => {
        get_video.getVideo(req, (data) => {
            res.redirect('/?data=' + data);
        });
    });
```

And my server:

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import get_video from './routes/main.route'

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));

app.get('/', (req, res)=> res.render('index', {title: 'My Homepage', msg: 'Hello World'}));
app.use('/clicked', get_video );

app.listen(5001, '0.0.0.0', ()=> console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5001/'))
```

Comment: please add a little more code than just the click handler

Comment: Can you please add a more elaborate code example and description of your problem? Then we're able to help you a bit better :)

Comment: @StefanN After this code there is a route /clicked that is fetching the data and returning the resultant url. Mainz007  helped with my second problem but my button is still not responding to multiple clicks. Though it does respond when there is no response coming from the route. i waited for one response to complete before clicking again, still not working. I am not very good with js, might be missing some basic.

Comment: how is `button`defined and what does the html look like. The first problem is only guessing without more code and html.

Comment: @Mainz007 I have added more code. Please see if that helps

Comment: I did a quick minimal fiddle with your code I got. Backend can't be the problem and the route seems to work as well, with adding the timestamp, so a static video as in my example should be no problem either. So only the first code snippet is relevant and works fine as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/1ntq9uvm/1/
With the code you gave me everything works fine. Are you using Internet Explorer? Please tell us what to do, to get your error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem could be solved just by adding a timestamp to your request. Because typically the browser cahces the response for /clicked. But if url is something like "clicked?ts=2019005081030", the video should still be requested, but the browser will always call the data from the server again, because the URL changed.
So:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     console.log('button was clicked');
     //Date.now() added for current date in milliseconds
     fetch('/clicked?ts=' + Date.now(), {method: 'GET'})
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.ok) {
            var url = response.url;
            var data = url.substring(28)
            var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
            document.querySelector("#myVideo > source").src = data;
            document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
            return;
        }
        throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
 });
```

Let me know if that solves already both problems or maybe give a little working example.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the caching problem, though still am not able to do a request on multiple button clicks. I have to refresh the page every time.

Comment: To fix that I would need more code. The only option I see right now: The `button`variable or attributes get changed so the eventListener is not reacting anymore.